# No Pagebreak before Chapter

Tags: page-breaking

I'm writing in docclass report. I'm writing a thesis which is divided up to two different topics. I'm using \part to split the topics. After the parts I use Chapter for the the titles. But before the first chapter of each topic, I want to have a title with the different parts.

```
\part{Secure data processing in an industrial enviroment}

\begin{center}
    {\textbf{\Huge{}Part 1:}} \\[0.5cm]
    {\textbf{\Huge{}Secure data processing in an industrial enviroment}}
\end{center}

%here is the pagebreak, which i dont want

\chapter{Abstract}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

Comment: Please always provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. That gives us a better idea as to exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Why are you adding the part title twice?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.